# d3.js change the colors of axis

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a program in d3.js (used in a html page) that generates graph & I want to lable my axis in differenet colours. Can u help  me?

```
$(function() {
    graph = simpleGraph()

        .title("Arduino Temperature Graph")
        .xmax(100).ymax(35)
        .xLabel("Time")
        .yLabel("Temperature");


    d3.select("#graph").call(graph)
        .attr("style", "font-size:12px;")
        .style("color", "#DE3378");


    $('#run-button').click(function() {
       setInterval(getData, 250);
        $('#run-button').html("Running...")
           .attr("disabled", true)
            .unbind();        
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to select the `text` elements and change their style.

Comment: tks a lot anyway. The problem was in css code: text -> stroke: blue